# countdown timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a JQuery Clock / Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer)

Does anyone knows countdown timer using javascript??

Comment: Not C# related (probably not asp.net related either?)

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure javascript, you would use the `setTimeout` method in a manner similar to this (treat this code as pseudocode, it is just to show the concept, I do not think it will work as-is):

```
countdown = function()
{
   var current = parseInt(document.getElementById("countdownBox").innerHTML);
   document.getElementById("countdownSpan").innerHTML = current;

   if (current > 0)
   {
       setTimeout('countdown()', 1000); // run every second
   }
}
```

You would start the countdown by writing something in the element with id `countdownBox` and calling `countdown()` for the first time.

Edit: note that the `setTimeout` method will tend to lose seconds if used this way - if you want real precision you will most likely have to synchronize externally every once in a while.

Answer (score -1):

The following will alert wow in 5 seconds.

`setTimeout ( 'wow()', 5000 );`

`function wow()
{
  alert('wow');
}`