# Auto Update when Passing Local Midnight in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about **auto-updating data when passing local midnight**.

#### Scenario

I am building a web app that contains `daily practice` content. Similar to Leetcode's everyday problem.

The `daily practice` will **auto-update when passing local midnight.**

#### Thoughts

I have searched a lot about repeating and auto-update posts. But most of them are related to `setInterval` which is **mainly repeating after certain time duration,** not to a certain time point.

There are two posts in the community:

[How to make Javascript time automatically update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470825/how-to-make-javascript-time-automatically-update)

[How to get date to auto refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27526857/how-to-get-date-to-auto-refresh)

---

**My naive solution**:

If I could compromise, not updating exactly at local midnight, I can use **setInterval with 24 hours**.  But it seems weird if a users found content updated at 2:00PM.

My question is: how to realize auto-update when **passing local midnight?**

Answer (score 0):

Then calculate how much time until midnight, and setTimeout to it. Helper function from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8583781/3807365

```js
function minutesUntilMidnight() {
  var midnight = new Date();
  midnight.setHours(24);
  midnight.setMinutes(0);
  midnight.setSeconds(0);
  midnight.setMilliseconds(0);
  return (midnight.getTime() - new Date().getTime()) / 1000 / 60;
}

function arm() {
  var minutes = minutesUntilMidnight();
  console.log(minutes.toFixed(2) + " minutes till midnight. that's " + (minutes / 60).toFixed(2) + " hours");
  setTimeout(function() {
    // your logic for refreshing here
    window.location.reload();

    // then, re-arm: 
    arm();
  }, minutes * 60 * 1000)
}

// usage:
arm();
```

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot.
Part of my concern is: The function here seems **only run once**.  If I want my app continuously automatically updated, do I need to add extra code like a while loop?

Comment: I will update my answer, but in this specific case it doesn't matter since the page reloads and starts over

Comment: Thanks! I will try it soon. One question, I see the code `arm()` recursively call itself. (`arm()` in the `function arm()`). Won't this cause a problem? I remember r**ecursion needs base case**.

Comment: Well, it is endless :-) But this isn't really recursion because it doesn't call itself but rather schedules itself ... something like that.

Comment: Cool. Will this endless thing cause some performance issue? Endless sounds like having some potential issue.  

This question seems naive but I am just so unfamiliar with this part :-(