# JQuery Clock / Timer since the page was loaded (even if user changes time on his computer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, time, timer

I've modified the code from [SO, provided by SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer) so make it work even if the user changes the time on his computer.

The time for `<div id="timer"></div>` still showing the real time since the page was loaded (even if the user changes the time on his computer).

When time changed, the alert appears (please see the code below).
The problem is: once time is changed, the alert appears the infinite number of times every second (but only one time is expected). Why is this happening?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var start = new Date;
    var end = (new Date - start) / 1000;
    setInterval(function () {
        if (Math.abs(end - (new Date - start) / 1000 )>1) {
            start = new Date - end * 1000;
            alert(Math.abs(end - (new Date - start) / 1000 ));
        }
        end = (new Date - start) / 1000;

        $('#timer').text(end + " Seconds");
    }, 100);
});
```

Comment: What's the purpose of all this?

Comment: The purpose of all this is to display the real time since the page was loaded.

Comment: Never dealt with a need to handle the case where the user changed the date... doesn't make sense... but just use `clearInterval` or something. but... still doesn't make too much sense to me.

Comment: Could you please answer my question  (if you can) why does the alert appear infinite number of times since the local time was changed? All the rest works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple - script execution is paused until the messagebox is closed. When you close it, the timer is already delayed and the condition is true again. You can test it yourself by duplicating the `alert[...]` line: if you close the first message fast enough, the second one will show something below 1.

Just replace `alert` with some HTML-based floating window and everything will be fine.