# Caching in asp.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to update my web page's time every 3 seconds. this is how how i'm trying to do it:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Time : " + DateTime.Now;

   return View();
}
```

but it does't refresh the page. Can someone please give me an idea how to solve this. thank you in advance!

Comment: it won't update page untill you send a request to your action. Better solution is to use javascript to update time using timer

Comment: Or take a look at SignalR if u would like data to be pushed in your page without you doing a pull

Comment: can you please give me a link to check out how to do it using javascript

Comment: OutputCache is something related to caching the responses temporally at the server and this will not refresh the page. Use JavaScript setTimeout to refresh/update some controls based on some interval.

Comment: [How to create a JQuery Clock / Timer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer)

Comment: By using Javascript SetInterval method and call url reload by window.location.reload();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Achieve it by using java script in asp form.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer() {
    var d = new Date();
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.toLocaleTimeString();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You also may use the meta tag for refreshing the page if it's ok to hit the server as below,

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;">
```