# Codeigniter real time/date (ticking)

Tags: codeigniter, time

Can someone can show me how to create time/date ticking in Codeigniter and explain that code? I am really confused right now, because started learning CI few days ago. I woud love to take date and time from server not from user PC. This is what ive done so far and stucked.

this is view file

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
            setInterval(timestamp, 1000);
        });

        function timestamp() {
            $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#timestamp').html(data);
            },
        });
    }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class = "page">
        <header>
            <time id="timestamp">
                <?php
                    date_default_timezone_set('YOUR TIMEZONE');
                    echo date('l d F Y - H:i:s');
                ?>
            </time>
```

Comment: You're using the wrong tool for the job. To do a ticking time, you will need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The task you want to achieve will be achieved by Javascript and not by Codeigniter. Read this post : [Creating real time ticking clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer?noredirect=1&lq=1)