# AJAX how to make real time timer to all user

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i need your help.
I need to make a real time timer in my webpage, but i need to operate it from backend (ex like start stop or reset).
Can anyone help me?, i didnt have any idea to make this thing
Sorry for my bad english.
thanks.
ps : the timer's time is same in all of users

Comment: Let me know if it works for you, or if you ment something different than what I've posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *ps : the timer's time is same in **all of users***

this would not be easy.

1. When admin start/pause/resume/stop timer. all client timer will started.
2. realtime
3. prevent bunch of request to server.

javascript only is not possible to doing this. if you are using javascript to check every certain time (setInterval), this will hard for server

to make this happens, i recommend you to use https://socket.io/

example: realtime chat, realtime notification is using websocket

good luck

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this?

[How to create a JQuery Clock / Timer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer)

This takes your date/time, and after every second it updates your time on the screen.