# Display Message and Timer: Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, timer

This is a Javascript code for the Memory game.

I have tried different time codes for this project including the ones I got from stack overflow but none are working.

The timer never displays. I am trying to make the timer display

- When the game starts
- During the game
- After the game

The short message or alert I want to displayed when a winner wins is not working.

Nothing really shows when a user wins.

Only the reset button resets the game.

What is the best way to have the timer show in these cases?

```js
/*
 * Create a list that holds all of your cards
 */
const cardSymbols = ['fa-diamond', 'fa-diamond', 'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-paper-plane-o', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-anchor', 'fa-bolt', 'fa-bolt',
                    'fa-cube', 'fa-cube', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-leaf', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bicycle', 'fa-bomb', 'fa-bomb'];

let shakeDeck = shuffle(cardSymbols);

/*
 * Display the cards on the page
 */

// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    let currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }
    return array;
}


function makeDeck() {
  $(".deck").empty()
  shakeDeck.forEach(function(card, index){
    const cardElement = '<li class="card"><i class="fa ' + card + '"></i></li>'
    $(".deck").append(cardElement);
  })
}

makeDeck();

var clicks = 0;

function lessStars(clicks) {
    var starRating = [5,10];
    var stars = starRating.length;
    $('.stars').children().each(function(i, starElem) {
    if (starRating[i] === clicks) $(starElem).addClass("star-lost")
  });
}

function forStar() {
  var val = $(".stars").html();
 return val;
}

function countMoves(clicks) {
  $('.moves').text(clicks);
}

function openModal() {
  $("#time-needed").text(timeNeeded);
  console.log(timeNeeded);
  $("#moves-needed").text(clicks);
  $("#score-panel").html(forStar());
  $("#myModal").modal("show")
}

var timerOn = false;

function playGame() {
  $(".card").click(function(){
    if (!timerOn) {
      getDate();
      timerOn = true;
    }
    const $card = $(this)
    if (!$card.hasClass("open show")) {
      $card.addClass("open show");
      if (!$compare) {
        $compare = $card;
        return
      }
      clicks++
      lessStars(clicks);
      countMoves(clicks);
      if ($compare[0].innerHTML === $card[0].innerHTML) {
        console.log("match");
        $card.addClass("match");
        $compare.addClass("match");
        $compare = null;
        matchCount++;
          if (matchCount === 8){
          openModal();
          clearInterval(timer)
          alert("Woohoo!! You Won!"+"Your total time is " + elapsedTime);
          }
      } else {
        console.log("doesn't match");
        setTimeout(function(){
          $card.removeClass("open show");
          $compare.removeClass("open show");
          $compare = null;
        },300)
    }
    } else {
      $card.attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
}

playGame();

let $compare = null
let matchCount = 0
var timer;
let timeNeeded = "";
var allSeconds = 0;

// timer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer#answer-19744442

function getDate(){
              // var start = new Date().getTime()
               timer = setInterval(function(){
               var currentTime = new Date().getTime()
               var elapsedTime = currentTime - currentTime
               let m = Math.floor((elapsedTime % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
               let s = Math.floor((elapsedTime % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
               if(s < 60){
                   s = "0"+s;
               }
               timeNeeded = m + ":" + s;
               $("h3").text(m+" : "+s);
               console.log(timeNeeded);
             }, 500);
    };

//    var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 1000);

//function myTimer() {
//    var d = new Date();
//}

function resetTimer() {
  var timerVariable = setInterval(getDate, 100);
  timeNeeded = "";
  clearInterval(getDate);
  getDate();
}

function resetGame() {
  clickCount = 0;
  timeNeeded = "";
  timer = false;
  clicks = 0;
  $('.stars').children().removeClass("star-lost")
  shuffle(cardSymbols);
  makeDeck();
  playGame();
  countMoves();
  resetTimer();
}

$('.restart').click(resetGame);



//this is the function for star ratings.
function check_stars(){
  if (moves < 11){
    stars[3].classList.add('fa-star-o');
    stars[3].classList.remove('fa-star');
  }
  else {
    stars[2].classList.add('fa-star-o');
    stars[2].classList.remove('fa-star');
  }
 /* else if(moves > 21){
    stars[1].classList.add('fa-star-o');
    stars[1].classList.remove('fa-star');
  }*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a timer like so:

```
var createTimer = () => {
  const start = Date.now();
  var done=false;
  const getMinuteSecond = now =>
    [
      Math.round((Date.now()-start)/60000), //minutes
      Math.round(((Date.now()-start)%60000)/1000) //seconds
    ];
  return {
    timePassed:()=>
      (done===false)
        ? [done,getMinuteSecond(Date.now())]
        : [true,done],
    stop:()=>
      done=getMinuteSecond(Date.now()),
    start:()=>done=false
  };
};
var updateTimePassed = timer => {
  const updateSomeHTML = html =>
    console.log("update",html);
  const intervalID = setInterval(
    _=>{
      const [done,update] = timer.timePassed();
      if(done){
        clearTimeout(intervalID);
      }
      updateSomeHTML(update);
    },
    1000
  )
};
//how to use:
var gameTimer = createTimer();
gameTimer.start();
updateTimePassed(gameTimer);
setTimeout(
  _=>gameTimer.stop(),
  3000
);
```

The `gameTimer` you can start and stop (not pause) the `updateTimePassed` can update time while playing (set html). There is a bit too much code to implement my code in yours but you can give it a try and let me know if you need help.

If you need more help please update your answer with the current code, what you expected to happen, what is actually happening and any possible errors in the console.