# jQuery Timer that refreshes a div element when the minute changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get a div element to update once one minute goes by from.
I have a function in Javascript that counts down to a specific time in the day, however, I would like to use JQuery so that as the timer is counting down when the minute changes instead of having to refresh the browser it does it without refreshing.

I had a timer that displayed hours, minutes, seconds counting down to a specific `setHours()` using a setTimout to countdown.

```
function countdown() {
  var now = new Date();
  var eventDate = new Date();

  var currentTiime = now.getTime();
  var eventTime = eventDate.setHours(16, 30, 0);

  var remTime = eventTime - currentTiime;

  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);


  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;


  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;



  document.getElementById("hours").textContent = h;
  document.getElementById("minutes").textContent = m;
  document.getElementById("seconds").textContent = s;
  if (now.getHours() >= 9 && currentTiime < eventTime) {
    setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
  }
```

At the moment I have a countdown that countdown to 16:30 but displays as:
Hours: minutes: seconds: I would like `Hours:xx minutes:xx` and when the minute goes down 1 minute it shows in the div without refreshing the page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! did you take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604450/how-to-create-a-jquery-clock-timer

Comment: yes just explains how to create a setinterval timer with JQeury but not how to create a timer that goes down and updates every second, and thanks!

Comment: The timer does update every second as you can see here https://jsfiddle.net/raghav710/tbvmj4px/1/ all that is to be done is to change the logic so that it counts down instead of up

Comment: Quick question. Since JQuery and JS both would update the page without refreshing it is there a specific reason why you would want to use only JQuery. Is concise code a reason?

Comment: The reason why I thought JQuery might need to be used is because the timer I have  does update every second however if I remove the minutes from showing and just have the hours and minutes showing it then requires the page to be refreshed to show a minute as passed by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that has a bit of JQuery strewn in. Please note that your Javascript solution will work as well. The only difference is that this calls `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` (['setInterval' vs 'setTimeout'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696692/setinterval-vs-settimeout))

Please try running the code snippet here or on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/raghav710/tbvmj4px/ . This updates the value *without* refreshing the page.

**EDIT:** Added condition to handle when the current time is greater than event time

```js
 function get_elapsed_time_string(total_seconds) {

  var now = new Date();
  var eventDate = new Date();

  var currentTime = now.getTime();
  var eventTime = eventDate.setHours(17, 00, 0);

  var remTime = eventTime - currentTime;

  if(remTime <= 0){
   clearInterval(interval_id);
    $("#hours").html(0);
    $("#minutes").html(0);
    $("#seconds").html(0);
  }

  var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
  var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
  var h = Math.floor(m / 60);


  h %= 24;
  m %= 60;
  s %= 60;

  h = (h < 10) ? "0" + h : h;
  m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m : m;
  s = (s < 10) ? "0" + s : s;

  $("#hours").html(h);
  $("#minutes").html(m);
  $("#seconds").html(s);

}

var elapsed_seconds = 0;
var interval_id =
setInterval(function() {
  elapsed_seconds = elapsed_seconds + 1;
  get_elapsed_time_string(elapsed_seconds);
  console.log(interval_id);
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hours"></div>
<div id="minutes"></div>
<div id="seconds"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks raghav this is really helpful, I am now going to see which would be more efficient for speed thank you.

Comment: @BradPlaydon happy to be of use! if you think this answers your question feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: @BradPlaydon what approach did you end up using?

Comment: so I used that JQuery but found that when it hit the time it would just zero out so I came up with another solution

Comment: @BradPlaydon feel free to post your solution as an answer to the question if you think it could help others looking for a similar solution

Answer (score 0):

```
function countdown(){
            var now = new Date();
            var eventDate = new Date();

            var currentTiime = now.getTime();
            var eventTime = eventDate.setHours(16, 30, 0);

            var remTime = eventTime - currentTiime;

            var s = Math.floor(remTime / 1000);
            var m = Math.floor(s / 60);
            var h = Math.floor(m / 60);


            h %= 24;
            m %= 60;
            s %= 60;

            h = (h < 10) ? h +" hrs" : h + "hrs";
            h = (h <= 1) ? "" : h;
            m = (m < 10) ? "0" + m + " mins" : m + " mins ";


          if(now.getHours() >= 9 && currentTiime < eventTime){
           setTimeout(countdown, 1000);
             document.getElementById("timer").textContent = h + " " + m;
             }

          else if(now.getHours() < 9 || currentTiime >= eventTime){
            var t = document.getElementsByClassName("order-day")[0];
            t.getElementsByClassName("order-day")[0].textContent = "Order by 4:30pm for same day dispatch";
             hideCountdown();
               }
```